# Перенос строки textarea

Tags: php

Проблема, в том, что при выводе текста в простой блок из БД, он отображается с переносами, как и задумано, а если вывести этот текст в textarea, то будет всё в одну строчку и будут отображаться теги 
.

Как сделать вывод в textarea с нормальными переносами?

Добавляю в базу текст таки образом

```
$text = str_replace("\r\n", "<br>", $_POST['text']);

$sql = "UPDATE `task` SET text = '".$text. "' WHERE weeks_day = ".$_GET['day'];
```

в textarea, он выводится таким

1. Поучить JS.
   2. Сходить в бассейн.

надо как-то сохранить в базу, таки образом

```
INSERT INTO `task` (`id`, `weeks_day`, `text`) VALUES (NULL, '2', '1. Поесть.\r\n2. Поспать.\r\n3. Поработать.\r\n4. Погулять.\r\n5. Посмотреть телевизор.');
```

Comment: А не надо текст менять при записи в базу, тогда проблем с его редактированием не получите.

Comment: Так сохраняется же всё в одну строку

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Для textarea делайте обратное преобразование:

```
<?php $txt = str_replace('<br>', "\n", 'text <br>text'); ?>

<form method="post">
    <textarea name="txt"><?= $txt ?></textarea>
    <br /><input type="submit" />
</form>
```

Но правильнее делать так, как сказано в комментарии выше.